# How can I install or import Bouncy Castle Cryptography API for Java; ZIP has no .class files; using netbeans ide

Tags: java, class, netbeans, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm having some difficulty installing Bouncy Castle for Java (installing is probably not the correct term, here, I understand that).

I navigated to their webiste, [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html), and downloaded version 1.6 of the lightweight API, as a ZIP file.  I extracted it to my Windows XP SP2 machine and expected it to be easy but it's not.  I attached it as a library to my NetBeans IDE project and quickly discovered that there are no .class files in this ZIP file.  I mean, I can only import .class files to my project, correct?  How do I 'install' Bouncy Castle?  Do I have to compile every .java file.  If so, how do I go about it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try extracting all the files into a folder, and then add that folder to your classpath. What kind of files are in the .zip?

Comment: It was an ID10T error.  I mistakenly downloaded the file marked in the source and doc file section.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a .jar file [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html), just download the .jar file and add it to your classpath, and you should be able to use the API.

Comment: can you tell me where do I get the jar for J2ME? There're only source zip.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you downloaded the "Sources & Docs" package accidentially. Try the section "Signed Jar Files" on [their site](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).